# Python hangs while executing pip and virtualenv and brings no results

Tags: python, cmd, pip, virtualenv, anaconda

I tried to set up a virtual environment for my project by executing `virtualenv myenv`. The folder seemed to be generated, but the command hung, and I couldn't execute another command. I had to close the console and restart cmd. The folder was generated, as I said, but I couldn't activate the virtual environment by `venv\Scripts\activate`.

I met the same behaviour while trying to execute `pip freeze > requirements.txt`. The file was generated, but it was empty, although I used a lot of packages in my project. When I executed just `pip freeze`, the list of packages was printed, but the command hung again, and I had to close the console again.

I tried both procedures many times, but with no success. I tried that in Windows cmd and Anaconda Prompt (Anaconda version: Anaconda3 2.4.1; Python: 3.5.1).

**EDIT**: when I tried to do this for the very first time some days ago, I succeeded in activating the virtual environment, but only for one time.

Comment: maybe try adding verbose flag output to each command, e.g. `pip -v`, `virtualenv -v`...etc.

Comment: @downshift Copying, copying, writing etc. Some "import bootstrap module" actions failed. Created all the .exe files. At the end: Successfully installed pip-9.0.1 setuptools-36.0.1 wheel-0.29.0 . And hangs again...

Comment: you might need admin priviledges. Try using `Powershell` with admin priv.

Comment: @TheDarkKnight Is admin priv. the same as opening cmd as admin (right click -> execute as Admin)?

Comment: that *should* work.

Comment: @TheDarkKnight Yeah that worked. Thank you a lot. You can post it as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: There you go @young_pythonist :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution to this (which *does* work) would be to use `Powershell` as an Administrator, instead of `cmd`.

Conversely, use `cmd` as an administrator, though I would recommend using the much-more powerful `Powershell` for any and all purposes!

> Why this works:

A lot of commands need super-user rights (think `root`/ `sudo` in linux) in order to be properly executed.

Since there is no such thing as as `sudo` in Windows yet, you can implement it via admin privileges.

Cheers!

Comment: You're doing something very wrong if you need admin access to create and use a virtual environment. Create it where you have access as a standard user.