# Making virtual environment with venv hangs

Tags: python, python-venv

When I'm trying to make a virtual environment using `python3 -m venv venv`, the process hangs. I then ran with verbose by running `python3 -v -m venv venv` and the last few lines are

```
# /Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.2/lib/python3.6/__pycache__/struct.cpython-36.pyc matches /Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.2/lib/python3.6/struct.py
# code object from '/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.2/lib/python3.6/__pycache__/struct.cpython-36.pyc'
# extension module '_struct' loaded from '/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.2/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_struct.cpython-36m-darwin.so'
# extension module '_struct' executed from '/Users/me/.pyenv/versions/3.6.2/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_struct.cpython-36m-darwin.so'
import '_struct' # <_frozen_importlib_external.ExtensionFileLoader object at 0x10cdf6d68>
import 'struct' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x10cdf6be0>
import 'gettext' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x10cdc5898>
import 'argparse' # <_frozen_importlib_external.SourceFileLoader object at 0x10ccd08d0>
```

What might be causing this to hang after this? I cannot find the script for `venv` to see what should happen next.

Answer (score 0):

You've answered the question during the question.

I'm assuming running it without sudo causes a process to hang as a specific process may need sudo privileges to run

Comment: I would prefer not to use `sudo`. I was hoping for advice on how to find what might be getting hung up. I have made virtual environments before without an issue.

Comment: you could change the users details to be root. i dont think theres a way around this. its linuxs' form of user security

Comment: did a bit of digging and found some info on another ticket : 
"A lot of commands need super-user rights (think root/ sudo in linux) in order to be properly executed.
"

apparently a work around for this could be to create the virtualenv in a location that has access as a standard user

Comment: Can you link that ticket?

Comment: sure : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44687986/python-hangs-while-executing-pip-and-virtualenv-and-brings-no-results/44695179#44695179

Comment: From the comments on that solution: "You're doing something very wrong if you need admin access to create and use a virtual environment. Create it where you have access as a standard user" - eryksun

You shouldn't be using root for things like creating a virtual environment or pip.